# Get a value at index from range

Tags: swift, range

I want to retrieve a random emoji inside the range.

```
let emojiRanges = [
                    0x1F601...0x1F64F,
                    0x1F680...0x1F6C0,
                ]
                let flattenEmoji = emojiRanges.flatten()
// the loop for emoji works
                for i in flattenEmoji {

                    let st = String(format:"0x%2X %@", i, String(UnicodeScalar(i)))
                    print(st)
                }

// but this is not possible to obtain value at wanted index
//there is a compiler error:
                let randomSign = String(UnicodeScalar(flattenEmoji[arc4random_uniform(UInt32(flattenEmoji.count))]))
                print("RANDOM \(randomSign)")
```

the error:

> ViewController.swift:68:67: Cannot subscript a value of type
>   'FlattenBidirectionalCollection<[Range]>' (aka
>   'FlattenBidirectionalCollection>>') with an index of
>   type 'UInt32'

What is the proper way to get a result?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that `flatten()` is lazily applied, and therefore returns a special [`FlattenBidirectionalCollection`](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/type/FlattenBidirectionalCollection/), which is indexed by a [`FlattenBidirectionalCollectionIndex`](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/type/FlattenBidirectionalCollectionIndex/), rather than an `Int`.

The simplest solution therefore would be to simply use the [`Array(_:)`](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/type/Array/#init_) constructor (or [`flatMap(_:)`](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/protocol/SequenceType/#func--flatmap-s_-sequencetype_-self-generator-element-throws-s)) in order to eagerly apply the flattening of the ranges, which will create an array that you can then subscript with an `Int`.

```
let flattenEmoji = Array(emojiRanges.flatten()) // In Swift 3, flatten() is named joined()

let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(flattenEmoji.count)))
let randomSign = String(UnicodeScalar(flattenEmoji[randomIndex]))
```

---

If you wish to keep the flattening being lazily applied, you could subscript the `FlattenBidirectionalCollection` directly (for Swift 2) through using [`advancedBy(_:)`](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/protocol/ForwardIndexType/#func-advancedby_) on the collection's [`startIndex`](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/protocol/CollectionType/#var-startindex_-self-index):

```
let randomIndex = flattenEmoji.startIndex.advancedBy(Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(flattenEmoji.count))))
let randomSign = String(UnicodeScalar(flattenEmoji[randomIndex]))
```

In Swift 3, as [collections move their indices](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0065-collections-move-indices.md), you'd want use the collection's [`index(_:offsetBy:)`](http://swiftdoc.org/v3.0/protocol/Collection/#func-index_offsetby_) method instead:

```
let randomIndex = flattenEmoji.index(flattenEmoji.startIndex, offsetBy: Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(flattenEmoji.count))))
```

Answer (score 4):

Change `emojiRanges` declaration to this:

```
let emojiRanges = Array(0x1F601...0x1F64F) + Array(0x1F680...0x1F6C0)
```

then life will become much easier.

```
for i in emojiRanges {
    let st = String(format:"0x%2X %@", i, String(UnicodeScalar(i)))
    print(st)
}
```

in `randomSign` you should convert index to `Int`

```
let randomSign = String(UnicodeScalar(emojiRanges[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(emojiRanges.count)))]))
print("RANDOM \(randomSign)")
```